# Excel VBA: Delete Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Delete_Sheets()


Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 6 To wb.Worksheets.Count

       Worksheets.Delete
       
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I'm trying to delete all sheets in a workbook from sheet number 6 on (first five always remain).

Why does this give me runtime erorr 1004?

Comment: `Worksheets` is the collection of all worksheets in the workbook and in your code it also refers to whichever workbook is active when the code runs.  Try `wb.Worksheets(i).Delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the comments and adding a Case statement to make sure your first 5 Sheets are excluded from the delete explicitly by name:

```
Sub Delete_Sheets()
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = wb.Worksheets.Count To 6 Step -1
    Select Case wb.Worksheets(i).Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"
            'Do nothing for the 5 worksheets named above
        Case Else
            wb.Worksheets(i).Delete
    End Select
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP's first 5 sheets retain their default names?  And why would that be relevant?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I guess I just assumed that adding an extra layer to make sure you don't lose something would be useful for the OP, but you are right it is an assumption and might not be needed,....

Comment: @chris_neilsen,
It is a good idea to check the sheets by name. A user could change the order of the sheets or add sheets.

Comment: @hennep re _It is a good idea to check the sheets by name_ 1) that's not what the OP asked for 2) a user can also change the sheet name 3) doing both ( name and index) isn't a great idea.  Pick one.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
For i = 6 To wb.Worksheets.Count  
       Worksheets(6).Delete 'yes: 6 don't 'fix' that answer
Next i
```